# Terminal command to notify if code has stopped running

Tags: python, windows, terminal, conda

I am running an ongoing command on a Windows Anaconda Powershell terminal to scrape Twitter data. I would like to be able to receive a notification if the code drops, preferably either email or SMS message. I've been able to find some packages that do this in OS but not Windows. Any ideas on how this could be set up?

Comment: You’re running a Python script?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a python script which call your code inside it and get notified using `knockknock`.

Comment: Thank you for this, looks very useful!